# Issue with Case and Extract Function

Tags: oracle

I am writing a SELECT Query as below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Number_of_rows
  FROM PAY_DETL
   WHERE 
    CASE 
    WHEN 
       Extract(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) > 9
    THEN 
    Extract(YEAR FROM PAY_EVT_BGN_DT) = Extract(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND Extract(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) > 9;
```

Where i am getting below error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword

statement where i am getting error is Extract(YEAR FROM PAY_EVT_BGN_DT "here")

Could someone please help me with above?

Thanks

Comment: I tried with END as well, still same error. I am trying to actually fetch a record (for a date range case )not assign. thats why i was using case in WHERE clause. Could you please let me know correct syntax?

Comment: I'm not going to down vote you but your where condition is unintelligible. If you could explain what you are trying to do in English I would be more than happy to try and help.

Answer (score 0):

A query nor a comment you posted help much; what does "not assign" mean?

Anyway: you can't use a conditional `WHERE` clause that way. A simple option is to split the query into two parts and `UNION` them, having the "distinguishing" parts of the `WHERE` clause opposite.

For example:

```
select count(*) as number_of_rows
from pay_detl
where extract(year from pay_evt_bgn_dt) = extract(year from current_date) 
  and extract(month from current_date) > 9      --> this condition ...
union
select count(*) as number_of_rows
from pay_detl
where condition_different_from_the_one_above
  and extract(month from current_date) <= 9     --> ... is just the opposite from this one
```

If it doesn't help, please, modify the question, provide test case so that we'd see the *input* and describe what would the *output* look like (based on that input).

Comment: thank you. The above query you have written can be used. But i used CASE because i have to make where clause based on 2 differnt condition. The purpose is to fetch record of 2 different year from that table (Eg - Oct 2017 to Sep 18). Pseudo code is below for today's date

If (current month is > 9 ) then where clause should consider only those records falling from Oct'18 to dec'18

else if (current month is < 9 ) then records should be fetched from Oct'17 to sept'18

Comment: OK; that's fairly simple to implement into a query I posted.

Answer (score 0):

We must differentiate the two main conditions `<,> 9`. Then, there is to account for each case:

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Extract(MONTH FROM SYSDATE)  > 9 THEN 
                      DECODE(Extract(YEAR FROM PAY_EVT_BGN_DT), Extract(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE), 1, 0) 
            END COUNT_MORE_NINE),
        SUM(CASE WHEN Extract(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) <= 9 THEN 
                      1 
            END COUNT_ANOTHER)
  FROM  PAY_DETL;
```